# Can I have npm packages in a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

***Please, let me know if this is question is *too broad*, or *primarily opinion-based****

I have my app in node.js with its normal `./node_modules/` folder, and I would like to install 1 specific npm package in a specific subfolder.

Is there any "counterproductive" advice I should be aware of before I can do that?
What if I would like to keep the two `./node_modules/` folders completely independent? Can I do that?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Comment: Could you give more context? The way you have it now makes it sound like you really have two separate projects and should just make one import/require the other.